# Need help with some regular polygon terminology.

Tags: geometry, terminology

I'm looking for the names of three different measures of a regular polygon.

- The name for the line between the centerpoint of the polygon, and any of its vertices.
- The name for the line between the centerpoint of the polygon, and the midpoint of any of it's sides.
- The name for a line between the centerpoint of the polygon, and any point on it's sides, at a certain angle. Right now I'd say something like "the radius at 75 degrees", but radius is a term for circles. The first two terms are special cases of this one.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is called a radius; the second is an apothem. "Apothem" is a somewhat obscure term and you should consider explaining it if you use it.

The length of the polygon's radius is also called its radius or its circumradius. The length of the apothem is also the apothem, and also called the inradius.

I don't know any general term for the third item and I guess your readers won't know it even if there is one.  Your best move is to make up a clear term like "75-radius" and define it clearly and explicitly.